# Twitter Bootstrap Modal data-dismiss

Tags: twitter, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to get modal data-dismiss action working to close the modal on click.  There seems to be an issue that I cannot find documented and hopefully someone here can shed some light on it.  Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'/>
    <title> Modal test </title>
    <link href='themes/default/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
    <link href='themes/default/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css'     rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>   
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-block">
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">x</a>
  <h4 class="alert-heading">Warning!</h4>
    Best check yo self, you're not...
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="themes/default/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

is the full suite of bootstrap including bootstrap-modal.js

I put in the `<div class="alert alert-block">` for testing the action, it seems to work in the alert but not the modal!

Comment: Are you calling the $("#myModal").modal('show') function? Here's a working fiddle with your example: http://jsfiddle.net/tPv7u/

Answer (score 2):

add this code please:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myModal').modal(); // initialized with defaults
        $('#myModal').modal('show'); // open your modal dialog
    });
</script>
```

Comment: 'Show' is by default set, so the two #myModal lines should do the same thing.